# Reverting to previous version of git revision and push it to make it the new head?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I need to make the latest version of git about 3 pushes ago, I'm not sure how to do it using TortoiseGit.

I've tried reverting changes from each commit until the one I want but that cuased a lot of unexpected issues with corruption and conflicting files.

I feel like there should be an easy way to simply say 'make revision xyz the latest and push that up'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [this wiki for instance](https://github.com/moneymanagerex/moneymanagerex/wiki/Working-with-Git-and-TortoiseGit-in-Windows#when-things-get-messed-up-that-synchronisation-with-master-cannot-be-achieved):

> - Use the TortoiseGit command: Git Show Log
> - Select the commit point before our problem started.
> - Use the TortoiseGit command: Reset "BRANCH" to this...
>
>   - Where BRANCH represents the name of the branch being used.
> - Use the Hard option
>
>   - This will remove all the commit points above this point in Git AND
>   - The working files will be reset back to the condition at that point of the project.

Then, still with TortoiseGit, [push with the force option activated](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-push.html#id629249).

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the commit which you think is the right revision. Let's say it's `abc123`.
2. For the branch in the remote repository you have pushed and updated, run `git push origin -f abc123:<branch_namr>`. It overwrites the branch with `abc123` as its new head commit. In case you may regret, you can create a backup branch from the current head `git branch foo`. And if you want to undo the force push, you can run `git push origin -f foo:<branch_name>`. If you don't have a backup, you can find the previous heads by `git reflog`.
3. For your local branch, run `git checkout <branch_name>;git reset abc123 --hard`.

Comment: OP is asking about TortoiseGit, which is a graphical interface to the repo that integrates into windows explorer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know. I just offer a solution. The task doesn't have to be done in TortoiseGit.

Comment: That's not really up to you to decide. But I happen to agree anyway.